# Problem with passing parameters from body-parser to Get JSON data

Tags: node.js, json, api

this is a simple code to get BTC price using api and parameters.
When I try this code I get undefined, but if i replaced "data.rates.crypto;" by "data.rates.BTC" I get a
the value of the current price despite the value of crypto is the same 'BTC'

```
app.post("/", function(req, res) {
  var crypto = req.body.crypto; //this line gives BTC
  var baseUrl = "http://api.coinlayer.com/api/live?access_key=lablabalab&symbols=";
  var finalUrl = baseUrl + crypto; //no problem here by passing the parameter whics is BTC
  request(finalUrl, function(error, response, body) {
    var data = JSON.parse(body);
    var price = data.rates.crypto;  //here is the problem
    res.write("<h1>Cuurent Price From " + crypto + " To USD is " + price + "</h1>");
    res.send();
  });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The response payload looks like this:

```
{"success":true,"terms":"https:\/\/coinlayer.com\/terms","privacy":"https:\/\/coinlayer.com\/privacy",
"timestamp":1611389888,
"target":"USD",
"rates":{"BTC":32728.891547}}
```

So you need to access `data.rates`, but the value of the `crypto` variable (BTC) rather than by the name `crypto`. You can do that with hash access:

```
var price = data.rates[crypto];
```